# Making tree from array

Tags: php

I have array:

```
$array = array(
         0 => 'aaa',
         1 => 'bbb',
         2 => 'ccc',
         3 => 'ddd'
        );
```

How can i make tree from this array? I would like receive:

```
$array = array(
         0 => 'aaabbbcccddd',
         1 => 'aaabbbccc',
         2 => 'aaabbb',
         3 => 'aaa'
        );
```

Comment: which is parent and node justify

Comment: I hate to say this, but have you tried anything yourself? If so, what? We'll help with problems, but we're not a homework factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
<?
$array = array(
             0 => 'aaa',
             1 => 'bbb',
             2 => 'ccc',
             3 => 'ddd'
            );

    for($i = count($array); $i>0; $i--){
        $newArry[] = implode($array);
        unset($array[$i-1]);
    }

    print_r($newArry);
?>
```

[Working CODE](http://codepad.org/uUzf4zeD)

Answer (score 0):

I answered according to your need. But this is not a tree.

```
$array = array(
             0 => 'aaa',
             1 => 'bbb',
             2 => 'ccc',
             3 => 'ddd'
            );

    $newArry=array();
    for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        $str=$array[$i];
        for($j=$i+1; $j<=count($array); $j++)
        {
                $str.=$array[$j];
        }   
        $newArry[]=$str;    

    }   

    print_r($newArry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
               'aaa',
               'bbb',
               'ccc',
               'ddd'
              );

$s = implode('', $array);

$a = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   $a[] = substr($s, 0, count($array) * 3 - $i * 3);
}

var_dump($a);
```